# i am running my code based on face recognition there is an error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

When running my code there is this error

> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of your problem?

Comment: I think the `gray` matrix is empty. can you try `print gray.shape` before calling the `detectMultiScale` method